# what is the Best approach to update the dashboard with server data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

I implementing dashboard kind of functionality. As shown in attached image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OECKH.png

For now I am continuously updating the dashboard with server info by calling the webservice after every 4 seconds.

So I am updating section values in fig (a). after every 4 seconds.

If i select one of the section. I am supposed to show the detail list view of the section. For that I am calling to web server again. Fig (b)

I am using the table view inside 0th row/cell of every section. Also once I select the section it should continously update the server changes inside inner detail list too.

To show details list view I am reloading section

So I want to know what is the best way to implement this scenario.

Any suggestion are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you know how much frequent your dash board data can be update on server side. If its less frequent then implement pull to refresh view. And request data on View will appear means if user go other screen and come back then refresh data

Comment: Thanks Atif,  Dashboard gets updated continuously. I means it should show the updates continuously as and when it finds it.